# Arducam OV6547 5MP camera

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

Im doing a project that is using the Arducam OV5647 camera and the raspberry pi 4b to do object detection and saving the images to a microsd card. I’m getting my code to upload with no errors but for some reason its not pulling up a window for me to see the camera. I’m  coding in python and using vscode as the platform. Is there something that I might be missing because I really need to get this to work.

I tried using the cv2.imshow function which is supposed to pull up a new window for the camera’s view. That isn’t working however. I have the camera’s width and height defined in my code too as 640 and 480 respectively.

Comment: Everytime I run my code, it waits for a couple of seconds and then just goes back to normal. I really don’t know how to fix this but I desperately need help.